# Test if on a certain page with php?

Tags: php

Using PHP, is there a way to test if the browser is accessing a certain page?

For example, I have a header file called header.php which is being pulled into a couple different pages.  What I want to do is when I go to a different page, I want to append certain variable to the title.

Example.

Inside header.php:

```
<?php 

$titleA = " Online Instruction";
$title B = "Offline";
?>

<h2>Copyright Info: <?php if ('onlineinstruction'.php) echo $titleA; ?> </h2>
```

edit: also if you believe there is  a simpler way to do this, let me know!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`,  or `__FILE__` depending on your version of PHP and how you have your code setup. If you are in a framework it may have a much more developer-friendly function available. For example, CodeIgniter has a function called `current_url()`

Per PHP Docs:

> $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']: The URI which was given in order to access
>   this page; for instance, '/index.html'.
>
> $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']: The filename of the currently executing script,
>   relative to the document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a
>   script at the address http://example.com/test.php/foo.bar would be
>   /test.php/foo.bar. The __ FILE__ constant contains the full path and
>   filename of the current (i.e. included) file. If PHP is running as a
>   command-line processor this variable contains the script name since
>   PHP 4.3.0. Previously it was not available.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
$pos = strrpos($url, "hello.php"); 

if($pos != false) {
    echo "found it at " . $pos; 
}


?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Comment: the hello.php is the string to check in the url variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this variable to find out what page you're on:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 0):

Any php page can include the following code, putting the applicable page title in the variable.

```
<?php

//Set Page Title for header template
$page_title = 'Welcome';

require_once("templates/header.php");

?>
```

In the header template:

```
<title><?php echo $pageTitle ?></title>
```

Any page called up will show your preferred title in the browser tab, and be usable as a variable on the specific page.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please rollback your answer to the first version. Code should never be posted as pictures, and using external sites is ok only if you have a lot of it. In this case they are literally 6 lines, they can certainly stay here on SO.